# Member of Array not evaluating correctly

Tags: batch-file

I wrote the following script today in response to another question but I can't get past an issue I'm having with my Array. For some reason, the variable I'm using inside of the array isn't evaluating properly. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set q=wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\directory\ldap PATH ds_computer get ds_name
set q1=NICCONFIG get DNSHostname^,IPAddress^,MACAddress
set /a "c=1" & set /a "inc=1" & set /a "inc2=0"
::for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('%q%') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=] " %%j in (
      'wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get deviceid^,volumeserialnumber^|find /N ":"') do (
            set "lines=%%j"
            set "v[!c!]=%%k" & set /a "c+=1"
            set "v[!c!]=%%l" & set /a "c+=1"
            if [!lines! equ [!c! goto :out
     )
    :out
    set c=
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%i in (
       'wmic /node:"wpcf-dc" OS get name^|find "|"') do (set v=%%i)
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims={}" %%b in (
       'wmic /NODE:"wpcf-dc" NICCONFIG Where IPEnabled^=TRUE get DNSHostname^,IPAddress^,MACAddress /FORMAT:TABLE^|find "{"'
      ) do ( For /F "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%e in ("%%~b %%~c %%d") do (
       echo(Host: %%e
       echo(IP: %%f
           echo(MAC: %%g
       echo(Windows Version: !v!
       set lines=!lines:[= !
       for /L %%l in (1,2,!lines!) do (
           set /a "inc2=%%l" & set /a "inc2+=1"
           echo value of inc2=!inc2!
           echo(Drive!inc!: !v[%%l]!
           echo(Volume!inc!: !v[!inc2!]!
           set /a "inc+=1"
       )     
      ) 
    )
 ::)
```

Here is the output I'm getting.

```
C:\Scripts\Batch>LDAPquery.cmd
Host: WPCF-DC
IP: 10.6.1.226
MAC: 00:11:43:EC:D4:B7
Windows Version: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition
value of inc2=2
Drive1: C:
Volume1: inc2
value of inc2=4
Drive2: D:
Volume2: inc2
```

I have no idea why inc2 isn't being evaluated inside of the array when the value of it is a number. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding this `set /a "inc2=%%l" & set /a "inc2+=1"` - without testing it in some cases a variable is only set at the end of the statement. Does splitting it into two lines help? (I didn't study the code, just noted that line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my version of your code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set q=wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\directory\ldap PATH ds_computer get ds_name
set q1=NICCONFIG get DNSHostname,IPAddress,MACAddress
set /a c=1, inc=1, inc2=0
::for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('%q%') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=] " %%j in (
      'wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get deviceid,volumeserialnumber^|find /N ":"') do (
        set "lines=%%j"
        set "v[!c!]=%%k" & set /a "c+=1"
        set "v[!c!]=%%l" & set /a "c+=1"
        if "!lines!" equ "!c!" goto :out
    )
    :out
    set c=
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%i in (
      'wmic /node:"wpcf-dc" OS get name^|find "|"') do "set v=%%i"
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims={}" %%b in (
      'wmic /NODE:"wpcf-dc" NICCONFIG Where IPEnabled=TRUE get DNSHostname,IPAddress,MACAddress /FORMAT:TABLE^|find "{"') do (
        for /F "tokens=1-3" %%e in ("%%~b %%~c %%d") do (
            echo Host: %%e
            echo IP: %%f
            echo MAC: %%g
            echo Windows Version: !v!
            set lines=!lines:[= !
            for /L %%l in (1,2,!lines!) do (
                set /a inc2=%%l+1
                echo value of inc2=!inc2!
                echo Drive!inc!: !v[%%l]!
                for %%v in (!inc2!) do echo Volume!inc!: !v[%%v]!
                set /a "inc+=1"
            )     
        ) 
    )
::)
```

I think this line must not be present:

```
set c=
```

I suggest you to be strict with justification columns in nested IF/FOR commands; this practice aids in finding unclosed parentheses. Also, don't use parentheses when they are not needed.

Note that this command `echo Volume!inc!: !v[!inc2!]!` can not be executed this way because the parsing of exclamation marks is achieved from left to right, so previous line means: echo "Volume"+value of "inc"+": "+value of "v["+"inc2"+value of "]". You must achieve the expansion of `!inc2!` in a FOR command and then use the replaceable parameter in the second expansion:

```
for %%v in (!inc2!) do echo Volume!inc!: !v[%%v]!
```

You may review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) for a further explanation of previous point.

You must note that if you activate the top-level `for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('%q%') do (`, then the `goto :out` command will break it when the GOTO is executed. The way to break just the nested `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=] " %%j in ( 'wmic ...` command, is by changing it this way:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=] " %%j in ('wmic ... ') do if "!lines!" neq "!c!" (
```

and eliminate both the `if ... goto :out` and the `:out` label.

Comment: Thank you Aacini, your answer was very enlightening. Thank you for the link to the post as well. That is a very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "v[2]=MyVolume"
set inc2=2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a inc=1
for /L %%l in (1,2,2) do (
   set /a inc2=%%l+1
   echo value of inc2=!inc2!
   echo(Volume!inc!: !v[!inc2!]!
   set /a "inc+=1"
)     
set /a inc=1
for /L %%l in (1,2,2) do (
   set /a "inc2=%%l+1
   echo value of inc2=!inc2!
   call echo(Volume!inc!: %%v[!inc2!]%%
   set /a "inc+=1"
)
```

Output is:

```
value of inc2=2
Volume1: inc2
value of inc2=2
Volume1: MyVolume
```